# Typescript throwing error during unit tests that variable undefined even though I have declare var statement at beginning of file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I'm using angular(2) and typescript. I'm using the moment library to convert dates so I have this function inside one of my utility classes:

```
static isoStringToDateObj(isoDateString: string): Date {
    // For unit tests and any environment where moment library is not present
    if (!moment) {
        return new Date(isoDateString);
    }
    return moment(isoDateString).toDate();
}
```

This works fine in the browser, but when I try to run my unit tests it throws the error:
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: moment in karma-test-shim.js (line 16240)

The line it is referring to is the `if (!moment)` line.

1. Why does it care if the variable does not exist in a statement that
   is only checking if the variable exists? It is not referencing any
   properties on it.
2. I have `declare var moment: any;` at the top of
   the file that the function isoStringToDateObj is in, so why is it
   saying reference error when the variable is actually declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only proper way to check if global variable does not exist is:

```
if (typeof moment === 'undefined') { ... }
```

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: moment

is runtime error, `declare var moment: any` cheats typing system to be silent about that but can't affect actual `moment` global in any way.

Comment: Note: a much cleaner solution instead of `declare var foo: any` is `declare var foo: foo_type | undefined`, this keeps most of the type-checking while still allowing `undefined`.